# Why is there a space between row's in bootstrap grid on mobile size?

Tags: html, css

Im wondering why do i have space between second text which is from first row and first text which is on second row? I find it annoying, why does it happen? Is there any way to fix it? 
[[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/2zhe0xg.jpg[/IMG]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViCZK.png)

This is how it looks on desktop:
[[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/2eby5bs.png[/IMG]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj4gY.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://static-assets-prod.epicgames.com/fortnite/static/webpack/8704d4d5ffd1c315ac8e2c805a585764.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4text">
                    <div class="b">
                        <p>Somethin ggoes here maybe</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://static-assets-prod.epicgames.com/fortnite/static/webpack/8704d4d5ffd1c315ac8e2c805a585764.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text">
                        <div class="b">
                            <p>Something goes here maybe</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5 ml-3 mr-3">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://static-assets-prod.epicgames.com/fortnite/static/webpack/8704d4d5ffd1c315ac8e2c805a585764.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text">
                        <div class="b">
                            <p>Somethin ggoes here maybe</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                            <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="https://static-assets-prod.epicgames.com/fortnite/static/webpack/8704d4d5ffd1c315ac8e2c805a585764.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text">
                            <div class="b">
                                <p>Something goes here maybe</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row > .text > .b {
display: -webkit-box;
height: 70%;
line-height: 1.3;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

}

I tried multiple solutions but couldnt get it to work

Comment: Surely `mt-5` and `mb-5` have nothing to do with this?

Comment: Nope i tested it, it only affected non mobile sizes aka bigger sizes. Since on desktop, laptops and tablets text is from the right of images hence why i used nested row's. Now its something to do with texts that move under images when sized to mobile version. I cant wirk it around. I just edited my post and put a picture how it looks on desktop.

Comment: Ok i fixed problem. Apparently it was about margins on both rows but i had to use media query to fix it and i stumbled on new problem after that fix for which i had to do another media query to fix it. Yep bootstrap's responsives isnt always working fine without media queries im sure that goes for other grid systems too.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

There are some styles you should definitely include in future questions so we can diagnose conflicts. For future reference, include any styles for classes you have assigned.

As far as what I can tell just from your code and screenshots, though, I'd say setting `margin: 0;` on your 2 divs in a media query for the affected breakpoint would work, but I'd also like to add a suggestion that will be a bit less messy for you using `flexbox`.

```css
/* Make your container a flexbox */

.container {
  display: flex;
}

/* Give flex grow value of 1 to keep all inner containers equal size */

.article {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* Sizing the image */

.article>img {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.article>h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* You could also just set the flex-direction to column, but displaying as block at the breakpoint will achieve the layout you're looking for on mobile. 500px is a trivial guess, use inspector to find the sweet spot */

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="article">
    <img src="https://3bonlp1aiidtbao4s10xacvn-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/epic-fortnite.jpg" />
    <h1>
      Something here maybe.
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="article">

    <img src="https://3bonlp1aiidtbao4s10xacvn-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/epic-fortnite.jpg" />
    <h1>
      Something here maybe.
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="article">

    <img src="https://3bonlp1aiidtbao4s10xacvn-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/epic-fortnite.jpg" />
    <h1>
      Something here maybe.
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="article">

    <img src="https://3bonlp1aiidtbao4s10xacvn-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/epic-fortnite.jpg" />
    <h1>
      Something here maybe.
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read up a bit more on `flexbox` in this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as well. If you're confused on anything here, feel free to comment and I'll try and answer the best I can. I've [composed a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/coyz6Ljf/18/) too so you can see how it responds when resizing.

Comment: Ok thqnk you alot for your answer i will surely look into it.